# How to determine when solr is done backing up?

Tags: linux, backup, solr

We are using SolrCloud and utilizing a the replication backup command:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/replication?command=backup&numberToKeep=5&location=/data/backup"
```

Which works great and responds with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">6</int></lst><str name="status">OK</str>
</response>
```

However, I'd like to rsync the files off of the box when the backup is done - but I dont know how to determine when it's finished. How can I know when it's done backing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was finally answered here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201304.mbox/%3CCAJt9WniZCAwOy+Bsw9e7vZULpOuVfvOOrKdm5RfqmKLtXc40Lw@mail.gmail.com%3E

```
it looks like the backup status is available via the details command, e.g.
<lst name="backup">
  <str name="startTime">Fri Apr 12 17:53:17 UTC 2013</str>
  <int name="fileCount">120</int>
  <str name="status">success</str>
  <str name="snapshotCompletedAt">Fri Apr 12 17:58:22 UTC 2013</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: Meaning this command: curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/replication?command=details"

Answer (score 0):

```
curl "http://foobar" && rsync foobar
```

&& continues upon success of the previous command.

Comment: curl returns instantly while the backup can take a few minutes when copying gigs of data.